# Looking for a Chrome Extension to Alias URLs for Easier Navigation

Tags: chrome, productivity, navigation, browser-extension

Community!

I am in search of a Chrome extension that enhances my browsing efficiency by allowing me to use URL aliases. Specifically, I need the functionality to create shortcuts for URLs so that I can navigate more quickly within the same webpage.

**Requirements**:

- Alias Creation: The ability to define short, memorable aliases for long URLs. For example, I'd like to set up an alias such as "sf/flow" that would redirect me to "/lightning/setup/Flows/home" on the same site.
- Context-Sensitive Redirection: The extension should be smart enough to apply the alias based on the current page's base URL. This means if I'm on https://asd.lightning.force.com/ and I use the alias "sf/flow", it should redirect me to https://asd.lightning.force.com/lightning/setup/Flows/home without needing to reload the page or navigate away.
- Ease of Use: Ideally, the extension should be user-friendly, allowing for easy management (addition, deletion, modification) of aliases.

**Use Case**:

As a frequent user of Salesforce's Lightning interface, I often find myself navigating to the Flows setup page. Currently, this requires manual navigation through the Salesforce interface or typing out the full URL. I'm looking for a solution that simplifies this process, saving time and enhancing productivity.

**Non-Requirements**:

- I do not need the extension to sync aliases across devices.
- The visual design of the extension's interface is not a primary concern, as long as it's functional and intuitive.

I appreciate any recommendations or insights from those who have used similar tools or know of extensions that meet these criteria. Thank you in advance for your help!